# Firebase phone authentication error in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting error for phone authentication. I received OTP successfully, but after I share my project with my team member with GitHub, I'm getting this errors.

I also I added MY SHA 1 & SHA 256 in my new firebase console. I also added dependencies, but still I get this error.

I also want to inform that after transfer my project with GitHub, I make new firebase account and add SHA 1 & SHA 256 in this project

Logcat:

```
03-16 16:19:40.001 8163-8163/com.roundtripride E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
03-16 16:19:40.679 8163-8235/com.roundtripride E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
03-16 16:19:40.713 8163-8163/com.roundtripride E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
03-16 16:19:41.202 8163-8201/com.roundtripride E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
03-16 16:19:41.202 8163-8163/com.roundtripride E/Tag: onVerificationFailed : This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
03-16 16:19:41.202 8163-8163/com.roundtripride E/Tag: onVerificationFailed : This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
03-16 16:19:41.202 8163-8163/com.roundtripride E/Tag: onVerificationFailed : com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
 implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
 implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
 implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
 implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:jackson-android-networking:1.0.2'
 implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.6.0'
 implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
}
```

Code:

```
public class OTPVerifyActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

 Context context;
 private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
 private String mVerificationId;
 String idToken = "", mobile;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verify);
    Utility.setLoginStatusColor(this);

    context = this;
    txt_finish = findViewById(R.id.txt_finish);
    edt_1 = findViewById(R.id.edt_1);

    
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mobile = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile");
    sendVerificationCode();

    txt_finish.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == txt_finish) {
        Utility.hideSoftKeyboard(edt_1, context);
        if (edt_1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Utility.errDialog("Please enter OTP", context);
        } else {
            verifyVerificationCode(edt_1.getText().toString().trim());
        }
    }
}

private void sendVerificationCode() {
    PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber("+91" + mobile)       // Phone number to verify
                    .setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                    .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                    .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
}

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        Log.e("Tag", "get Data : " + phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode());
        Utility.dismissProgressDialog(pd);
        String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            edt_1.setText(code);
            verifyVerificationCode(code);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        Utility.dismissProgressDialog(pd);
        Log.e("Tag", "onVerificationFailed : " + e.getMessage());
        Log.e("Tag", "onVerificationFailed : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.e("Tag", "onVerificationFailed : " + e.toString());
        Utility.errDialog(e.getMessage(), context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        mVerificationId = s;
        Utility.dismissProgressDialog(pd);
    }
};

private void verifyVerificationCode(String code) {
    //Log.e("Tag","Verify code : "+code);
    pd = Utility.showProgressDialog(context);
    try {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Tag", "PhoneAuthCredential Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(OTPVerifyActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        user.getIdToken(true)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                                            Utility.dismissProgressDialog(pd);
                                            Log.e("Tag", "Success OTP " + isDriver);
                                            MyPreference.setPreferenceValue(context,"isLogin","true");
                                           
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        Utility.dismissProgressDialog(pd);
                        //verification unsuccessful.. display an error message
                        String message = "Something is wrong, we will fix it soon...";
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            message = "Invalid code entered...";
                        }
                        Log.e("Tag", message);
                        Utility.errDialog(message, context);
                    }
                }
            });
  }

}
```

Comment: please share your logcat

Comment: https://prnt.sc/10n6h4q   My logcate screenshot link

Comment: after send otp it will open browser for app verification

Comment: its look like you denied for it

Comment: or please check google service replace or not.

Comment: no i didn't denied it .. i know that browser should open but browser didn't open

Comment: in otp sms you get any url or not?

Comment: I didn't get any sms from firebase

Comment: please try my answer

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove your debug SHA-1 and SHA-256 from your old firebase account .
2. Open android studio and click on gradle in right corner > click your project > select app > select tasks > select android > click on signing report > copy our SHA1 and SHA-256 from there.
3. Add SHA1 and SHA-256 in your new firebase account .(if you are building apk from 2 system add both system's SHA1 and SHA-256).
4. You need to make sure that you enabled PHONE AUTHENTICATION in Firebase console => Authentication => Sign-in Methods.
5. Add dependency in build.gradle(:app)

   implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
6. Go to google cloud console , select your project .
7. Click on navigation menu and select APis & services and then select Dashboard .
8. Click on enable api and services and enable api " Android Device Verification".
9. Download and replace the latest google-services.json file in your project.

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'

please add this dependency then check sha1 and sha256 one more time then try it

Comment: I already added it and I also mention it in my question

Comment: please remove app from first firebase account

Comment: Make sure sha1 and sha256 generate on same device which use to build apk.